# Flutter, specify a wrapper widget for each child in column

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

in my Flutter app I have a column with dynamically created children:

```
Column (
    children: _getWidgetsList(),
);
```

My goal is to **wrap each item** that's returned from `_getWidgetsList()` with`Flexible` widget so that all the items can be distributed evenly on the screen.

Unfortunately, if I do that in `_getWidgetsList()` I get an error:

> The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Is is possible to somehow specify a wrapper for each child in the Column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try mapping the children like this :

```dart
Column (
    children: _getWidgetsList().map((e) => Flexible(child: e,)).toList(),
);
```